# How to set a radio group background with icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-group

This is **activitiy_radio_group.xml**

```
 <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/bottom_radio_group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_group_background">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"/>

            </RadioGroup>
```

I want set background using xml so that when we check first radio button then it should show on icon and when unchecked it should show off icon.

I am trying using this **drawable_radio_group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selecteditem_dot" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nonselecteditem_dot" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

But its not working icon is not changed. Please suggest me how fix it .

Comment: try using directly don't create any `drawable_radio_group.xml` file. Just add your image file because selector only work with clickable items and radio group don't hold state checked / unchecked property.